# How to get a list of Google Cloud services with their description?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm looking for a way to list all the Google could services with a short description similar to the one found on this [product page](https://cloud.google.com/products/). A previous solution consisted of scraping the products web pages, but the result wasn't satisfying.

I already did this for IBM cloud services where I exploited the cloudfoundry API to retrieve these information. I'm looking for a similar solution for google services.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the [API Discovery Service](https://developers.google.com/discovery/) supplied by Google.

Here's the API endpoint (JSON formatted) that lists all the services with descriptions:
https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis

Answer (score 1):

A jQuery selector like this should do the trick

```
$('.cloud-product-card__headline').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text().trim() + ": " + $(this).next('.cloud-product-card__sub-headline').text().trim())
})
```

Outputs:

```
Compute Engine: Scalable, high performance VMs.
App Engine: PaaS for apps and backends.
Kubernetes Engine: Run containerized applications.
Cloud Functions: Event-driven serverless compute platform.
Cloud SQL: MySQL and PostgreSQL database service.
Cloud Bigtable: NoSQL wide-column database service.
Cloud Spanner: Mission-critical, scalable, relational database service.
Cloud Datastore: NoSQL document database service.
Firebase Realtime Database: Store and sync data in real time.
Stackdriver: Powerful management tools for GCP and AWS.
Monitoring: Monitoring for applications on GCP and AWS.
Logging: Logging for applications on GCP and AWS.
Error Reporting: Identifies and helps you understand application errors.
Trace: Find performance bottlenecks in production.
Debugger: Investigate code behavior in production.
Profiler: Low-impact CPU and heap profiling to reduce latency.
Cloud Deployment Manager: Manage cloud resources with simple templates.
Cloud Console: GCP’s integrated management console.
Cloud Shell: Command-line management from any browser.
Cloud Mobile App: Manage GCP services from your mobile device.
Cloud Billing API: Programmatically manage GCP billing.
Cloud APIs: Programmatic interfaces for all GCP services.
Apigee API Platform: Develop, secure, deploy, and monitor your APIs everywhere.
Apigee Healthcare APIx: Accelerate building new FHIR API-based digital services.
Apigee Open Banking APIx: Accelerate open banking and PSD2 compliance.
Apigee Sense: Intelligent behavior detection to protect APIs from attacks.
API Analytics: Insight into operational and business metrics for APIs.
API Monetization: Flexible, easy-to-use solution to realize value from APIs.
Cloud Endpoints: Develop, deploy, and manage APIs on GCP.
Developer Portal: Enable developers and API teams with a turnkey self-service platform.
Cloud Storage: Object storage with global edge-caching.
Persistent Disk: Block storage for VM instances.
Cloud Memorystore: Fully managed in-memory data store service.
Cloud Firestore: NoSQL document database service with syncing for mobile apps
Cloud Storage for Firebase: Store and serve content with ease.
Cloud Filestore: Store and serve content with ease.
Data Transfer: Command line tools for developers to transfer data over the network.
Transfer Appliance: Rackable storage server for shipping large volumes of data to Google Cloud.
Cloud Storage Transfer Service: Transfer data between cloud storage services such as AWS S3 and Google Cloud Storage.
BigQuery Data Transfer Service: Fully managed data import service for BigQuery.
Virtual Private Cloud (VPC): VPC networking for GCP resources.
Cloud Load Balancing: High-performance, scalable load balancing.
Cloud Armor: Protect your services against DoS and web attacks
Cloud CDN: Content delivery on Google's global network.
Cloud Interconnect: Connect directly to GCP’s network edge.
Cloud DNS: Reliable, resilient, low-latency DNS serving.
Network Service Tiers: Optimize your network for performance or cost.
Cloud SDK: CLI for GCP products and services.
Container Registry: Fast, private image storage.
Container Builder: Fast, consistent, reliable builds.
Cloud Source Repositories: Private Git repositories hosted on GCP.
Cloud Tools for IntelliJ: Debug production cloud apps inside IntelliJ.
Cloud Tools for PowerShell: Full cloud control from Windows PowerShell.
Cloud Tools for Visual Studio: Deploy Visual Studio applications to GCP.
Cloud Tools for Eclipse: Deploy Eclipse projects to GCP.
Gradle App Engine Plugin: Use Gradle for your App Engine projects.
Maven App Engine Plugin: Use Maven for your App Engine projects.
Cloud Test Lab: On-demand testing infrastructure for Android apps.
Firebase Crashlytics: Prioritize and fix stability issues faster.
Cloud IoT Core: Secure device connection and management.
Google Beacon Platform*: Create proximity-based experiences.
Anvato: Stream live and on-demand video to any device.
Zync Render: Render directly from your 3D modeling tools, quickly and cost efficiently.
BigQuery: Fully managed cloud data warehouse.
Cloud Dataflow: Real-time batch and stream data processing.
Cloud Dataproc: Managed Spark and Hadoop service.
Cloud Datalab: Explore, analyze, and visualize large datasets.
Cloud Dataprep: Explore, clean, and prepare data for analysis.
Cloud Pub/Sub: Ingest event streams from anywhere, at any scale.
Genomics: Power your science with Google Genomics.
Google Analytics 360 Suite*: Enterprise analytics for better customer experiences.
Google Data Studio*: Tell great data stories to support better business decisions Compare to QuickSite or Power BI.
Firebase Performance Monitoring: Gain insight into your app's performance.
Cloud AutoML: Machine learning made easy.
Cloud TPU: Train and run ML models faster than ever.
Cloud Machine Learning Engine: Build superior models and deploy them into production.
Cloud Job Discovery: Job search and recommendations powered by ML.
Dialogflow Enterprise Edition: Create conversational experiences across devices and platforms.
Cloud Natural Language: Derive insights from unstructured text.
Cloud Speech-to-Text: Speech-to-text conversion powered by ML.
Cloud Text-to-Speech: Text-to-speech conversion powered by ML.
Cloud Translation API: Dynamically translate most language pairs.
Cloud Vision API: Derive insight from images powered by ML.
Cloud Video Intelligence: Extract metadata from videos.
Firebase Predictions: Define dynamic user groups based on predicted behavior.
Cloud IAM: Fine-grained identity and access management.
Firebase Authentication: Simple, free multi-platform sign-in.
Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy: Use identity to guard access.
Cloud Data Loss Prevention API: Discover and redact sensitive data.
Security Key Enforcement: Prevent phishing with security keys.
Cloud Key Management Service: Manage encryption keys on GCP.
Resource Manager: Hierarchically manage resources on GCP.
Cloud Security Command Center: Comprehensive security and data risk platform for GCP.
Cloud Security Scanner: Automatically scan your App Engine apps.
Access Transparency: Get visibility over your cloud provider through near real-time logs.
Gmail: Smart, secure email for modern businesses.
Calendar: Online calendars designed for teams.
Hangouts Chat: Secure team messaging.
Hangouts Meet: Easy-to-join video meetings.
Google+: Secure corporate social network.
Admin: Manage G Suite for your organization.
Vault: Archiving and eDiscovery for email, files, and chat.
Mobile Device Management: Mobile management for Android, iOS, Windows, and more.
Docs: Documents with real-time co-editing.
Sheets: Smart, fast online spreadsheets.
Slides: Beautiful presentations created together.
Forms: Easy-to-create surveys and forms.
Sites: Easy-to-build team sites.
Keep: Capture ideas and keep organized.
Drive: Secure cloud storage and file sharing.
Cloud Search: Powerful search across G Suite.
Maps: Bring the real world to your users with customized maps and Street View imagery.
Routes: Help your users get from A to Z with comprehensive data and real-time traffic.
Places: Help users discover the world with rich details for over 100 million points of interest.
Ridesharing: Integrate Google Maps into your ridesharing app for reliable, real-time routing.
Gaming: Create immersive, real-world games anywhere on the globe.
Asset tracking: Accurate, real-time global location data for fleets, assets, and devices.
Chrome Enterprise: Easily manage Chromebooks with Chrome OS and Browser.
Android Enterprise: Securely deploy intelligent devices, OS, and business apps.
Jamboard: A collaborative, digital whiteboard to visualize your ideas.
Hangouts Meet hardware: Fast, effective video meetings for the conference room.
Consulting: Develop your cloud strategy with the people who know it best.
Advanced Solutions Lab: Build a solution side by side with our machine learning experts.
Certification: Earn your Google Certification in data engineering, cloud architecture, and more.
Technical Account Management: Work with a Google expert to help build your roadmap for long-term success.
Training: Train your team with in-person classes or virtual training (live or on-demand).
QwikLabs: Practice your cloud technologies and software skills with on-demand, hands-on labs.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `services.list` [method](https://cloud.google.com/billing/reference/rest/v1/services/list) from the [Billing API](https://cloud.google.com/billing/v1/getting-started). This will return a list of the services provided by Google Cloud Platform. A call to `services.list` will output something like this:

```
{
 "services": [
  {
   "name": "services/02DA-B362-D983",
   "serviceId": "02DA-B362-D983",
   "displayName": "Cloud Text-to-Speech API"
  },
  {
   "name": "services/04C4-B046-D8B2",
   "serviceId": "04C4-B046-D8B2",
   "displayName": "Cloud Natural Language API"
  },

  // the lis is long...

  {
   "name": "services/FE65-6566-F37B",
   "serviceId": "FE65-6566-F37B",
   "displayName": "Komprise"
  }
 ]
}
```

For each of these, you can then call the `services.skus.list` [method](https://cloud.google.com/billing/reference/rest/v1/services.skus/list) and get a description of each service (see [SKU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_keeping_unit)). For `services/04C4-B046-D8B2` -Cloud Natural Language API- you would get:

```
{
 "skus": [
  {
   "description": "Content Classification Operations",
   "category": {
    "serviceDisplayName": "Cloud Natural Language API"
   }
  },
  {
   "description": "Entity Analysis Operations",
   "category": {
    "serviceDisplayName": "Cloud Natural Language API"
   }
  },
    // More details
  }
 ]
}
```

Enable the [Billing API](https://cloud.google.com/billing/reference/rest/) and see both methods in the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scrape cloud.google.com/products for products w description:

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

(async () => {
  let gcpdom;
  try {
    console.log("Calling Google Products Page ...")
    gcpdom = await JSDOM.fromURL("https://cloud.google.com/products");
    const products = gcpdom.window.document.querySelectorAll(".cws-headline");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Error Reading https://cloud.google.com/products")
  }

  try {
    console.log("Scraping Google Products Page ...")
    let arrayOfProductObjects = [];
    const products = gcpdom.window.document.querySelectorAll(".cws-headline");
    for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
      let desc = products[i];
      if(products[i]){
        if(products[i].nextElementSibling){
          if (products[i].nextElementSibling.classList.contains("cws-body")){
            let obj = {};
            obj.product = products[i].innerHTML.trim();
            obj.description = products[i].nextElementSibling.innerHTML.trim();
            arrayOfProductObjects.push(obj);
          }
        }        
      }
    }
    const callArray = [];
    const ids = arrayOfProductObjects.map(o => o.product)
    const filtered = arrayOfProductObjects.filter(({product}, index) => !ids.includes(product, index + 1))
    for (let i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
      console.log(filtered[i].product + " : " + filtered[i].description)
    }
    console.log(filtered.length + " GCP products found...");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("error scraping google best practices");
  } finally {
    console.log('Done.');
  }
})().catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
})
```